# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::substr

Tags: c++, substr

I received this error: *"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr"* from this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

vector <string> n_cartelle;

ifstream in("n_cartelle.txt");
string linea;

while(getline(in,linea))
n_cartelle.push_back(linea);


for(int i=0; i < 4; ++i){


if(n_cartelle[i].substr(n_cartelle[i].size()-3) == "txt")
cout <<"si"<<endl;
else
cout<<"no"<<endl;

}
```

If I try with this:

```
if(n_cartelle[7].substr(n_cartelle[7].size()-3) == "txt")
cout <<"si "<<n_cartelle[7]<<endl;
else
cout<<"no"<<endl;
```

I don't get the error.

Comment: I don't have problem to compile this code but to execute in windows 7 pro.

Comment: The size of the string from which you're trying to extract the substring is probably less than 3 characters. Print the string, and it's size within the `for` before you try to extract the substring.

Answer (score 17):

What you experience is probably a case of an exception falling off `main()`, which terminates the program and gives an OS-specific error message like the one you posted.

As a first measure, you can catch exceptions in `main()`. This will prevent your program from crashing.

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    catch (std::exception const &exc)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception caught " << exc.what() << "\n";
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Unknown exception caught\n";
    }
}
```

Now that you have this mechanism in place, you can actually hunt down the error.

Looking at your code, it *could* be that `n_cartelle` has less than 4 elements, caused perhaps by n_cartelle.txt containing only 3 lines. This would mean that `n_cartelle[0]`, `n_cartelle[1]` and `n_cartelle[2]` would be fine, but trying to access `n_cartelle[3]` and anything beyond would be undefined behaviour, which basically means that *anything* can happen. So first make sure that `n_cartelle` actually has 4 elements and that your program has defined behaviour.

The next thing which could go wrong (more likely, to be honest) is your `substr()` call. When you try to call `substr()` with "impossible" arguments, for example getting the substring starting at character 10 of a string containing only 5 characters, then the behaviour is *a defined error* - a `std::out_of_range` exception is thrown. The same happens (indirectly, almost every time) when you accidentally try to pass a negative number as the first argument of `substr()`. Due to the internal workings of a `std::string`, a negative number would be converted to a huge positive number, certainly much longer than the string, and result in the same `std::out_of_range` exception.

So, if one of your lines has a length less than 3 characters, `size() - 3` is negative and what I just explained happens.